# Mathematica not simplifying rational powers in complex expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have the following expressions and I would like to obtain a final result purely in the real domain.

```
Refine[Sqrt[-1] / Sqrt[a^3], Assumptions -> a<0]

Refine[Sqrt[-1] / a^(3/2), Assumptions -> a<0]
```

The first expression is simplified to

```
1 / (-a)^(3/2)
```

while the second one is kept as

i / a^(3/2)

How can I force the first simplification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way might be

```
expr = Sqrt[-1]/a^(3/2);
Assuming[a < 0, Simplify[ComplexExpand[expr]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PowerExpand[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Btw, you will not get the same exact expressions in both cases you showed.

This is because $\sqrt{a^3} = a^{3/2}$ only for $a\geq 0$ and you said that $a<0$.

```
ClearAll[a]
Reduce[ Sqrt[a^3] == a^(3/2) && Element[a, Reals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]